# Vague convergence - equivalence?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Are the following definitions of vague convergence equivalent?

The sequence of s.p.m $\mu_n$ vaguely converges to $\mu$ iff

[(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/10693/edit) There exists a dense subset $D$ of the real line $\mathbb{R}$  so that $ \forall a \text{ and } b \in D \text{ with } a <b, \mu_n((a,b]) \rightarrow \mu((a,b])$.

[(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380386/weak-vague-convergence) For all $f\in C_K^+ (\mathbb R)$ we have  $\int f \mu_n \rightarrow \int f \mu$.

A source connecting these two definitions is also welcome.

Proof idea: Use the fact that $L^2$ functions like indicators are dense in $C$. Also $C$ functions can be approxdimated by simple functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right in fact.
The core of proof is the D-valued approximation lemma.
You can even let $f \in C_0$. And you can find the total proof in A Course in Probability Theory written by Kai Lai Chung.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check out the book.